# Firebase Rules: Only let users edit own profile but create new users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have spent the last day trying to do something on firebase rules, but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. I am quite new to this Firebase rules thing, so please have patience :)

I have the following rules at the moment:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        ".write": "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid",
        ".read": "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That only lets users with the same id read and write their data. But, the problem is a bit more complex.

If a new user registers, there is no record of that user in the database. So I need to create a new node inside users. How can I do that? I don't know where to place the conditions so they don't interfere with each other.

A little bit of explanation would be great, I am quite lost with this kind of rules. Or if you recommend a better way to approach this, please let me know!

This is the code I'm using to create a new user:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users'); 
usersRef.push({"hlo": "asdsd"});
```

But it gives me PERMISSION_DENIED.

Comment: What do you mean "interfere with each other"? With your current rules, registering a new user shouldn't be a problem. Did you test it?

Comment: It does not work. So if I am trying to add a new node to users, it won't let me. It will say PERMISSION_DENIED.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to add a new node

Comment: Here is the code:

var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');

      usersRef.push({"hlo": "asdsd"});

Comment: Try using this instead: `var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users'); var uid = usersRef.push().key; usersRef.child(uid).set({"hlo": "asdsd"});`

Comment: Thanks a million. You got me to the solution. That actually doesnt work, but I wrote:

var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
       var uid = usersRef.push().key;
       usersRef.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({"hlo": "asdsd"});

And that worked. What does the usersRef.push().key do? Just for curiosity? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Oh, you did great. Sorry, I forgot you have a `auth.uid` rule... the `push()` will create a new node on the database with a random key. `push().key` returns this random key. I don't think you need that line anymore.

Comment: Thank you again, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are perfectly fine. The problem is the code you're using to write a new user. You're creating a random key and it won't match the current user's uid. You should get the user uid from Firebase Auth:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
usersRef.child(uid).set({"hlo": "asdsd"});
```